# Does "manifest" mean the same as show and illustrate?

Tags: word-usage

When I describe *the information of a graph*, can I use ***manifest*** instead of *show* or *illustrate*? I am a bit hesitant because when I look up manifest in a dictionary, it says the meaning of manifest is

> to show a feeling, attitude etc.

I am not sure. Can it be used in such a context?

Comment: Why use a more ambiguous word when at least two clearer ones exist?

Comment: You need to give the sentence in which you will use "manifest". Could you do that?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use ***manifest*** in your context. The dictionary definitions can be vague, but that's why most of them also give examples. So if you look at [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/manifest), it says it means:

> to show something clearly, through signs or actions

Which could make you think that the graph can "manifest" something. But when you look at the examples, you can intuitively understand that *manifest* really means *to express* OR *show signs/symptoms of*:

> - The workers chose to ***manifest*** their dissatisfaction in a series of strikes. [express]
> - Kipper ***manifested*** no joy or disappointment, but remained in his chair, calm and unconcerned. [showed signs of]

Here is another definition and example by [OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=manifest%20meaning&sxsrf=ALeKk03ZtnoQOryzzP47MnkE14UtL-VXZA%3A1629881474924&source=hp&ei=ggQmYZaRNsmFhbIPkfCPkAQ&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAYSYSkoIC29OpG9Z1SCGUkL5cGxpXN9g9&oq=manifest%20me&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIICAAQgAQQsQMyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCC4QgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQ6BAgjECc6BQgAEJECOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARCjAjoOCC4QgAQQsQMQxwEQowI6CAguELEDEIMBOgkIIxAnEEYQ-QE6CAguEIAEELEDOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToLCC4QgAQQsQMQgwE6CwguEIAEELEDEJMCUPMFWPMWYKkhaABwAHgCgAGyBIgBoBCSAQs1LjMuMC4xLjEuMZgBAKABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz):

> show (***a quality or feeling***) by one's acts or appearance; ***demonstrate***.
>
> - Lizzy ***manifested*** signs of severe depression [showed symptoms].

So ***manifest*** is rather used with abstract concepts like feelings, qualities, symptoms, signs. It would be uncommon to use it with a graph. This [GNgram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2A_NOUN%20manifests&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A_NOUN%20manifests%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BGod_NOUN%20manifests%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdisease_NOUN%20manifests%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blife_NOUN%20manifests%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bspirit_NOUN%20manifests%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnature_NOUN%20manifests%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bauthor_NOUN%20manifests%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpower_NOUN%20manifests%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmind_NOUN%20manifests%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bduplicate_NOUN%20manifests%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BChrist_NOUN%20manifests%3B%2Cc0) will show you which nouns are most commonly used as subjects of *manifest*. This [other GNgram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=manifests%20%2A_NOUN&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cmanifests%20%2A_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmanifests%20God_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmanifests%20symptoms_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmanifests%20signs_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmanifests%20something_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmanifests%20nothing_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmanifests%20intent_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmanifests%20power_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmanifests%20assent_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmanifests%20none_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmanifests%20design_NOUN%3B%2Cc0) shows which nouns are most commonly the object of *manifest*.

I would stick to ***show*** and ***illustrate***, and if you are too bored of them and wish to avoid repeating them all the time, there are always handy words like *indicate, reveal, clarify, demonstrate*, etc. depending on what you want to state in the sentence.

Comment: I see! Many thanks for the specific explanation!!!

Comment: Two of the contexts which spring to mind for "manifest" are Freudian psychology and ghosts (and related spirit manifestations). As you say, these are about latent or non-corporeal things given physical form.

Comment: @StuartF It is also very much used in religious language to refer to _epiphanies of divinity_ or of _divine attributes_.

Answer (score 0):

It's rare, but some have done so.

> An average plotted on a graph **manifests** a series of deviations
> around a mean – the average performance over time. ([USA Today](https://www.usatoday.com/story/money/markets/2014/08/31/adviceiq-bargains-amid-downturns/14807359/))
>
> The fuel sending unit resistance does not exhibit a perfectly linear
> trace when graphed.  Instead the graph **manifests** a very shallow
> S-shaped curve. ([Chevy Truck Forum](http://forum.73-87chevytrucks.com/smforum/index.php?topic=31010.15))
>
> The graph **manifests** trends in your data. ([Ward Systems
> Group](http://www.wardsystems.com/neuroshell2.asp))
>
> The bilayer graph **manifests** the categorization, with the first
> layer comprising the nodes each of which denotes one information
> consumer and the second layer comprising the nodes each of which
> denotes one feature extracted. ([US patent application](https://uspto.report/patent/app/20190295111?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=pmd_r4hILOtm0h_DgUW_KfxtCErHFigfZvyAPWcZv1lklW4-1629883734-0-gqNtZGzNAiWjcnBszQal))
>
> This graph **manifests** the same theme as that exhibited in the
> distribution of the words " might* " and " power* " shown below. (COCA
> Bible Wheel, [now offline](https://web.archive.org/web/20180322004417/https://www.biblewheel.com/Topics/WordDistributions.php))

In any case, the above seem intelligible given the definition given in the [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/113484?rskey=JnOz83&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> To make (a quality, fact, etc.) evident to the eye or to the
> understanding; to show plainly, disclose, reveal.

Answer (score 0):

I think there can be a subtle difference of tone.

If you are fairly sure of some phenomenon and you have produced a graph for the purpose of telling or educating others about it, then "show" or "illustrate" would be appropriate.

If, however, you are engaged in an investigation or experiment and you have graphs showing the results of various experiments or surveys, and you have not yet reached definite conclusions, you might say e.g. "The graph of heat loss in situation X manifests the same effect as in situation Y but differs from Z..."

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use **manifest** in your context. The most appropriate word for you is **illustrate**. Of course you're free to use any synonymous expression as you wish.

### illustrate

**1)** Make clear, elucidate, explain; esp. clarify or support using examples, give an example or illustration of, exemplify. *He chose his quotations to **illustrate** how…the present can always be illuminated by the past.*

**2)** Support or clarify (a description, account, etc.) using drawings, photographs, or other pictures; esp. provide (a book, magazine article, etc.) with pictorial illustrations. *The route is not without its hazards as the picture…**illustrates**.*

**Source**: SOED (Shorter Oxford English Dictionary)

### Manifest

To indicate the most unmistakable or clearest revealing [among its cluster of synonyms]. It suggests something that requires no investigation but is plainly evident to anyone. **1)** *A hunger that **manifested** itself in strange ways*. **2)** *A region **manifesting** a luxuriance of flora and fauna.*

**Source**: [Choose the Right Word](https://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/choose-the-right-word-s-i-hayakawa/1002516046;jsessionid=8C46A52EB4026619B2F9B97BD3CA4922.prodny_store01-atgap10?ean=9780062731319)

The term **show** is the broadest among its cluster of synonyms.